# Base Controller with all basic autowired services

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I am developing a web application with spring 4. I have more no of controllers. Under them most of the controller use same services. So I planned to move all those common services to a common controller and extend it from the actual controller.

Here are my classes.

**B.java**

```
class B{
    final static Logger _log = Logger.getLogger(BaseController.class.getName());

    public B( {

    }



    //common methods
}
```

**TR.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("myrequests/transfer")
public class TRController extends B{
    final static Logger _log = Logger.getLogger(TRController.class.getName());


    @Autowired
    public TRController(IInstitutionService institutionService,  HttpServletRequest request, ModelMapper modelMapper, ITransferService transferService) {
        super(institutionService, accessService, userService,  request, modelMapper, assetService);
        this.transferService = transferService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createRequest(ModelMap model) {
        TransferRequest transferRequest = new TransferRequest();
        User loggedInUser = userService.findByUserId(getPrincipal());
        transferRequest.setRequesterContactNo(loggedInUser.getExtension());
        transferRequest.setRequesterEmail(loggedInUser.getEmail());
        return "newtransferrequest";
    }
}
```

Like above I have more controllers which extends BaseController. Is this right approach? Are I am doing anything wrong in the design?

Comment: controllers are different from services. Rename BaseController to BaseService, let Service classes extend the Base service to access the common services. If you have many common endpoints shared across many apps then it is a different question altogether.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, a good approach is to let the controller be the controller and service to do the service part (all the heavy lifting and business logic of the app). Don't try to cram controller and service in one class.

Common practice is to have the controller class clean. You can add various controller methods that point to various service classes extended from a base service class. Try that, you will see your code much cleaner.